# What is the meaning of this symbol in php

Tags: php

What is the use of the following symbols in php?

```
<?= code($data); ?>
```

Though I don't know the actual use of the above symbol, I found out that I can use

```
<?= my_function($data1,$data2); ?>
```

instead of using

```
<?php echo my_function($data1,$data2); ?>
```

Can anyone explain what exactly is happening here and what is the use of it?

Comment: [Are PHP short tags acceptable to use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use)

Comment: Great i found the answer here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php) ...

Answer (score 0):

It's a quick way of echoing text, as that's one of the most common uses of PHP.

Answer (score 0):

As of PHP 5.4, `<?= ?>` is essentially the short-hand way of writing `<?php ?>`.